# Is there any possible to map the default response in dialogflow

Tags: android, chatbot, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

```
1st question: Tell me about fees
Response from Intent: Tuition fees or transportation fees
2nd question: Tuition fees
Response from Intent:Please select Grade
3rd question: Grade1
```

Is there any possible way to map both 2nd question and 3rd question such as"tuition fees Grade 1"?

Comment: Can you update the question with screen shots showing the intent or intents you're using? There are a lot of ways to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use required entities. This is how I solved the problem:

I created entities:
[image]
[image]

[image]

I listed things that the user may say. I also matched the entities that the user may say to the entities that I created.
[image]

I set the entities as required
[image]

I defined custom prompts for the required entities. [image]

I made a response saying what the person selected. Instead of just repeating what the users says here, you may want to call a webhook. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvCBUoVQmM4) I talk about webhooks.
[image]

Comment: Oh yeah, I have a dialog that you can interact with here:
https://bot.dialogflow.com/48d6dc8d-2c46-4e8c-973d-76b4b02442b6